# Running 16-bit programs using Wine in Cygwin on 64-bit Windows

Tags: cygwin, wine, 16-bit

I was motivated to install old programs after digging up disks of UB Funkeys and SimCity 2000. I wanted to run them without a hungry VM environment that didn't feel streamlined. I am also a legal idiot, so I didn't want to run SimCity 2000 with a copy of Windows 3.1 (I don't want to pay money either).

I tried compiling wine on Cygwin to run some really old (16-bit?) apps like SimCity 2000 and UB Funkeys since my computer is a 64-bit system.

I used this guide: http://web.archive.org/web/20151215100244/http://wiki.winehq.org/WineOnWindows#head-0b0ea2607765eef2d73f0bcb510560859105539c

However, I cannot find the .wine or c-drive directory in Cygwin, So I couldn't setup my old programs.

Are there any suggestions/alternatives to solving this problem?

Comment: I expect troubles.  x64 chips have multiple modes, including a backwards-compatibility mode that can run 16-bit code, and a 64-bit enhanced mode that loses that compatibility.  64-bit operating systems tend to put CPU in the enhanced mode.  So you'd need to re-implement the 16-bit instruction set, and I'm guessing Wine doesn't do that (even though it implements other things).  Wine is meant for translating software, but still relies on the CPU.  I suggest considering Sim City 2k for DOS, and using DOSBox.

Comment: @BrianLuHappyville101 I think you should get a result with Bash on Windows 10.